# Proof of The Greatest Integer Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove the following statement where [.] denotes the greatest integer function and {.} denotes the fractional part?

If a, b are real numbers, then $[a + b] = [a] + [b]$ if and only if $\{a\} + \{b\} < 1$.

Comment: The key is that $a=[a]+\{a\}$, with $0\leq \{a\}<1$ (and likewise for $b$.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I tried that but nothing. Am I forgeting something else?

Comment: @user463019, maybe that, that means [a+b]=[[a]+{a}+[b]+{b}]

Comment: Given that you haven't shown what you've tried, maybe you could. Try to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a = [a] + {a} and b = [b] + {b}

[a + b] = [[a] + {a} + [b] + {b}] = [([a] + [b]) + ({a} + {b})]

The above expression is of the form I + r where 'I' is an integer and 'r' is a real number between 0 and 1 as {a} + {b} < 1

Hence [I + r] = I = [a] + [b]

Hence Proved

Comment: That only proves the "if" part, not the "only if" part.

Comment: You just have to do the opposite for only if.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of "$\rightarrow$" by contraposition

Assume $\{a\}+\{b\}\geq 1$.
$$\implies [a+b]=[[a]+[b]+\{a\}+\{b\}]= [[a]+[b]+1]=[a]+[b]+1$$
$$\implies [a+b]\neq [a]+[b]$$

Proof of "$\leftarrow$"

Assume $\{a\}+\{b\}< 1$.
$$\implies [a+b]=[[a]+[b]+\{a\}+\{b\}]=[a]+[b]+[\{a\}+\{b\}]=[a]+[b],$$

since $[\{a\}+\{b\}]=0$.